# Create trigger to UPPER() Firebird data

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a query to UPDATE or INSERT data in my Firebird, but this values come from what user type, so  I want to create a pattern, all data as Upper.

It's possible do it in Firebird 2.5?

My #1 test

```
"UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ENTIDADE_001 (CODCLI,NAME) VALUES UPPER('$erp_codcli','$erp_codcli')"
```

My #2 test

```
"UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ENTIDADE_001 (CODCLI,NAME) VALUES UPPER(('$erp_codcli','$erp_codcli'))"
```

Comment: create `BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT TRIGGER` - see https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-trgr.html

Comment: `UPPER('$erp_codcli','$erp_codcli')` - here seem to be two mistakes. 1) `UPPER` function has ONE parameter, so you have to call it twice, once per parameter - `VALUES( UPPER('$erp_codcli'),  UPPER('$erp_codcli') )` - https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-string 2) string splicing is VERY fragile and dangerous technique, making your programs unpredictable and unreliable! Use SQL parameters. You didn't disclose your programming language but you may find many examples at http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Also your question's text and title contradict one another. The text says you want to make a "pattern of [insert] query" while the title says you want a "trigger" that would work AFTER the query and override any values the query inserted. Both options are doable, but they are DIFFERENT approaches

Comment: @Arioch'The you right and 1st point! 2nd I will read more, how I'm learning, a lot of details go unnoticed. 3rd, idiom problem, the "pattern" that I write is view in my DB standardized.

Comment: Well, now "view".... Thing is, "view" is yet another type of SQL objects as in `CREATE VIEW ENTIDADE_UPPER AS SELECT UPPER(CODCLI) as CODCLI, UPPER(NAME) as NAME FROM  ENTIDADE_001` and later `select * from ENTIDADE_UPPER` - which should be yet another, THIRD possible approach to the task :-) So, be careful when choosing words, many are already reserved in the context of SQL, and they will imply yet different goal you could have in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your update or insert statements is that they are syntactically incorrect. The `VALUES` clause takes a value list, and `UPPER(...)` is not a value list, see the syntax of [`UPDATE OR INSERT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update-or-insert):

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO
   {target} [(<column_list>)]
   VALUES (<value_list>)
   [MATCHING (<column_list>)]
   [RETURNING <values> [INTO <variables>]]

<column_list>      ::=  colname  [, colname  ...]
<value_list>       ::=  value    [, value    ...]
<ret_values>       ::=  ret_value    [, ret_value    ...]
<variables>        ::=  :varname [, :varname ...]
```

Secondly, [`UPPER`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-upper) is a function that takes a single argument.

The syntactically correct version of your statement is:

```sql
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ENTIDADE_001 (CODCLI,NAME) 
  VALUES (UPPER('$erp_codcli'), UPPER('$erp_codcli'))
```

However, as Arioch 'The also said in the comments, string interpolation like this is unsafe and makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use a parameterized prepared statement, and set the values to the parameters instead.

As to the question asked in the title of your question how to create a trigger, see the Firebird documentation on [triggers](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-triggers). A simple example of a trigger that does what you want would be:

```sql
create trigger ENTIDADE_001_UPPERCASE 
  active before insert or update on ENTIDADE_001
as
begin
  new.CODCLI = upper(new.CODCLI);
  new.NAME = upper(new.NAME);
end
```

See this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=02d56eaa5b173226b71a58fbd3f47539) for a working example.

Comment: Frankly, `SQL injection` - which you only mentioned - might be not seen seriously by many people, because of "aliens ain't go here" environments or because they are novices desperate to make at least something working first. Personally i find all kind of datatypes and especially date/time and NULL conversions more practical argument of the three (preparing queries for reuse being the 3rd) against splicing.

Comment: Both are right, this is a test, but not is the best way to do this. I will study more about create a clean code. :) Thank you @Arioch'The and Mark Rotteveel